# Variable length integer encoding in Java

Tags: java, integer

I have coded up the variable length integer encoding aka [VLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) in Java. It works with any base in `(1, 128]`. I've implemented the usual encode/decode methods and also the addition and multiplication for this encoding. Single byte multiplication uses [shift-and-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add) and multi-byte ones uses [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).

I've tested the code to a certain extent (unit tests accompany the code) though it is easy to miss a few cases, especially when manipulating bits. It'll be be helpful if more pairs of eyes look at the code too.

The code is hosted on [github](https://github.com/leakycup/stuff/blob/master/java/practice/src/main/java/me/soubhik/IntegerEncoding.java) too.

updated to add argument validation in `encode()`. also added test cases for large (`> Long.MAX_VALUE`) integers.

```
package me.soubhik;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Created by soubhik on 06-08-2016.
 */
public class IntegerEncoding {
    public static interface IntegerCode {
        //index==0 => Most Significant
        public byte[] encode(int x);
        public int decode(byte[] code);
        public byte[] add(byte[] a, byte[] b);
        public byte[] sub(byte[] a, byte[] b);
        public byte[] mult(byte[] a, byte[] b);
        public boolean isValid(byte[] a);
        public byte[] fromDecimalString(String decimalString);

        default public String toBinaryString(byte[] code) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (byte c: code) {
                String byteAsString = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(c & 0xff)).replace(' ', '0');
                builder.append(byteAsString);
                builder.append(' ');
            }

            return builder.toString().trim();
        }

        default public byte[] fromBinaryString(String byteString) {
            assert (StringUtils.isNotBlank(byteString));

            String[] byteStringArray = byteString.split(" ");
            byte[] code = new byte[byteStringArray.length];

            int idx = 0;
            for (String aByte: byteStringArray) {
                byte b = (byte)(Integer.parseInt(aByte, 2) & 0x000000ff);
                code[idx] = b;
                idx++;
            }
            assert (isValid(code));

            return code;
        }
    }

    //see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity
    //also, Lucene VInt type : http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/fileformats.html
    //base can be any integer in (1, 128]
    public static class VLQ implements IntegerCode {
        private static final byte MASK = (byte)(1 << 7);
        private static final int DEFAULT_BASE = 128;

        private final int base;

        public VLQ() {
            this(DEFAULT_BASE);
        }

        public VLQ(int base) {
            assert (base > 1);
            assert (base <= DEFAULT_BASE);

            this.base = base;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] encode(int x) {
            assert (x >= 0);

            if (x == 0) {
                return new byte[] {0};
            }

            long extractRemainder = base;
            long extractByte = 1;
            ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
            while (x >= extractByte) {
                int remainder = (int)(x % extractRemainder);
                byte b = (byte)(remainder / extractByte);
                bytes.add(b);
                extractByte *= base;
                extractRemainder *= base;
            }

            byte[] result = toByteArray(bytes, bytes.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
                result[i] = (byte)(result[i] | MASK);
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] fromDecimalString(String decimalString) {
            assert (StringUtils.isNotBlank(decimalString));

            final byte[] tenToThePower9 = encode(1000000000);

            byte[] code = encode(0);
            byte[] multiplier = encode(1);
            int end = decimalString.length();
            int start = end - 9;
            while (start >= 0) {
                String digitsToConvert = decimalString.substring(start, end);
                int digitsAsInt;
                try {
                    digitsAsInt = Integer.parseInt(digitsToConvert);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return null;
                }
                byte[] digitsAsCode = encode(digitsAsInt);
                digitsAsCode = mult(digitsAsCode, multiplier);
                code = add(digitsAsCode, code);

                multiplier = mult(multiplier, tenToThePower9);
                end = start;
                start -= 9;
            }

            if (end > 0) {
                String digitsToConvert = decimalString.substring(0, end);
                int digitsAsInt;
                try {
                    digitsAsInt = Integer.parseInt(digitsToConvert);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return null;
                }
                byte[] digitsAsCode = encode(digitsAsInt);
                digitsAsCode = mult(digitsAsCode, multiplier);
                code = add(digitsAsCode, code);
            }

            return code;
        }

        @Override
        public int decode(byte[] code) {
            int multiplier = 1;
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = code.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int b = code[i] & (~MASK);
                result += b*multiplier;
                multiplier *= base;
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(byte[] x) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
                byte b = x[i];
                if ((b & MASK) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }

                b &= ~MASK;
                if ((b >= base) || (b < 0)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if ((x[x.length - 1] >= base) || (x[x.length - 1] < 0))  {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] add(byte[] x, byte[] y) {
            return add(x, 0, x.length, y, 0, y.length);
        }

        private byte[] add(byte[] x, int xStart, int xEnd, byte[] y, int yStart, int yEnd) {
            assert (xEnd > xStart);
            assert (yEnd > yStart);

            int xLen = xEnd  - xStart;
            int yLen = yEnd - yStart;

            int maxLen, minLen, maxArrayStart;
            byte[] maxArray;
            if (xLen >= yLen) {
                maxLen = xLen;
                minLen = yLen;
                maxArray = x;
                maxArrayStart = xStart;
            } else {
                maxLen = yLen;
                minLen = xLen;
                maxArray = y;
                maxArrayStart = yStart;
            }

            ArrayList<Byte> result = new ArrayList<>(maxLen + 1);
            int carry = 0;
            int idx = 0;
            for (; idx < minLen; idx++) {
                int xIdx = xStart + xLen - 1 - idx;
                int yIdx = yStart + yLen - 1 - idx;
                byte a = (byte)(x[xIdx] & (~MASK));
                byte b = (byte)(y[yIdx] & (~MASK));
                int sum = a + b + carry;
                if (sum >= base) {
                    sum -= base;
                    carry = 1;
                } else {
                    carry = 0;
                }
                result.add((byte)sum);
            }

            for (; idx < maxLen; idx++) {
                int bIdx = maxArrayStart + maxLen - 1 - idx;
                byte b = (byte)(maxArray[bIdx] & (~MASK));
                int sum = b + carry;
                if (sum >= base) {
                    sum -= base;
                    carry = 1;
                } else {
                    carry = 0;
                }
                result.add((byte)sum);
            }

            int resultLen = maxLen;
            if (carry == 1) {
                result.add((byte)carry);
                resultLen++;
            }

            byte[] sum = toByteArray(result, resultLen);
            for (int i = 0; i < sum.length - 1; i++) {
                sum[i] |= MASK;
            }
            sum[sum.length-1] &= ~MASK;

            return sum;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sub(byte[] x, byte[] y) {
            return sub(x, 0, x.length, y, 0, y.length);
        }

        public byte[] sub(byte[] x, int xStart, int xEnd, byte[] y, int yStart, int yEnd) {
            assert (xEnd > xStart);

            byte paddingByte = MASK;
            int newYStart = yStart;
            for (; newYStart < yEnd - 1; newYStart++) {
                if (y[newYStart] != paddingByte) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            yStart = newYStart;
            assert (yEnd > yStart);

            int xLen = xEnd  - xStart;
            int yLen = yEnd - yStart;
            assert (xLen >= yLen);

            int maxLength = xLen;
            int minLength = yLen;
            byte[] maxArray = x;

            ArrayList<Byte> result = new ArrayList<>(maxLength);
            int resultLen = 1;
            int borrow = 0;
            int idx = 0;
            for (; idx < minLength; idx++) {
                int xIdx = xStart + xLen - 1 - idx;
                int yIdx = yStart + yLen - 1 - idx;
                byte xValue = (byte)(x[xIdx] & (~MASK));
                byte yValue = (byte)(y[yIdx] & (~MASK));
                int nextBorrow = 0;
                if (xValue < (yValue + borrow)) {
                    xValue += base;
                    nextBorrow = 1;
                }
                byte s = (byte)(xValue - yValue - borrow);
                result.add(s);
                if (s != 0) {
                    resultLen = idx + 1;
                }
                borrow = nextBorrow;
            }

            for (; idx < maxLength; idx++) {
                int xIdx = xStart + xLen - 1 - idx;
                byte xValue = (byte)(maxArray[xIdx] & (~MASK));
                int nextBorrow = 0;
                if (xValue < borrow) {
                    xValue += base;
                    nextBorrow = 1;
                }
                byte s = (byte)(xValue - borrow);
                result.add(s);
                if (s != 0) {
                    resultLen = idx + 1;
                }
                borrow = nextBorrow;
            }

            byte[] resultBytes = toByteArray(result, resultLen);
            for (int i = 0; i < resultBytes.length - 1; i++) {
                resultBytes[i] |= MASK;
            }

            return resultBytes;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] mult(byte[] x, byte[] y) {
            if (x.length > y.length) {
                y = paddLeft(y, x.length - y.length);
            } else if (x.length < y.length) {
                x = paddLeft(x, y.length - x.length);
            }
            return unpaddLeft(multKaratsuba(x, 0, x.length, y, 0, y.length));
        }

        //fast multiplication using Karatsuba algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm
        private byte[] multKaratsuba(byte[] x, int xStart, int xEnd, byte[] y, int yStart, int yEnd) {
            assert (xEnd > xStart);
            assert (yEnd > yStart);

            int xLen = xEnd - xStart;
            int yLen = yEnd - yStart;
            assert (xLen == yLen);

            if (xLen == 1) {
                return multByte(x[xStart], y[yStart]);
            }

            byte[] z2 = multKaratsuba(x, xStart, xStart + xLen/2, y, yStart, yStart + yLen/2);
            byte[] z0 = multKaratsuba(x, xStart + xLen/2, xEnd, y, yStart + yLen/2, yEnd);

            byte[] x0plusx1 = add(x, xStart, xStart + xLen / 2, x, xStart + xLen / 2, xEnd);
            byte[] y0plusy1 = add(y, yStart, yStart + yLen/2, y, yStart + yLen/2, yEnd);
            if (x0plusx1.length > y0plusy1.length) {
                y0plusy1 = paddLeft(y0plusy1, x0plusx1.length - y0plusy1.length);
            } else if (x0plusx1.length < y0plusy1.length) {
                x0plusx1 = paddLeft(x0plusx1, y0plusy1.length - x0plusx1.length);
            }
            byte[] z1 = multKaratsuba(x0plusx1, 0, x0plusx1.length, y0plusy1, 0, y0plusy1.length);
            z1 = sub(z1, z2);
            z1 = sub(z1, z0);

            int ceilingOfLenBy2 = (xLen + 1)/2;
            z2 = multByBasePowerN(z2, 2*ceilingOfLenBy2);
            z1 = multByBasePowerN(z1, ceilingOfLenBy2);
            byte[] result = add(z1, z2);
            result = add(result, z0);

            return result;
        }

        //shift and add multiplication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm
        private byte[] multByte(byte b1, byte b2) {
            b1 &= ~MASK;
            b2 &= ~MASK;
            byte mask = 1;
            byte shift = 0;
            int tempResult = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                if ((b2 & mask) > 0) {
                    tempResult += b1 << shift;
                }
                shift++;
                mask <<= 1;
            }

            return encode(tempResult);
        }

        private byte[] multByBasePowerN(byte[] x, int n) {
            assert (n >= 0);

            if (n == 0) {
                return x;
            }

            byte[] result = new byte[x.length + n];
            System.arraycopy(x, 0, result, 0, x.length);
            byte paddingByte = MASK;
            Arrays.fill(result, x.length, result.length, paddingByte);
            result[x.length - 1] |= MASK;
            result[result.length - 1] &= ~MASK;

            return result;
        }

        private byte[] paddLeft(byte[] original, int n) {
            byte[] padded = new byte[original.length + n];
            byte paddingByte = MASK;
            Arrays.fill(padded, 0, n, paddingByte);
            System.arraycopy(original, 0, padded, n, original.length);

            return padded;
        }

        private byte[] unpaddLeft(byte[] original) {
            int numPaddingBytes = 0;
            byte padddingByte = MASK;
            for (int i = 0; i < original.length - 1; i++) {
                if (original[i] != padddingByte) {
                    break;
                }
                numPaddingBytes++;
            }

            if (numPaddingBytes == 0) {
                return original;
            }

            int unpaddedLength = original.length - numPaddingBytes;
            byte[] unpadded = new byte[unpaddedLength];
            System.arraycopy(original, numPaddingBytes, unpadded, 0, unpaddedLength);

            return unpadded;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] toByteArray(Iterable<Byte> bytes, int length) {
        byte[] result = new byte[length];

        Iterator<Byte> bytesIterator = bytes.iterator();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            assert (bytesIterator.hasNext());

            byte b = bytesIterator.next();
            result[i] = b;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void encodeDecodeTest(int[] values, IntegerCode coder) {
        for (int v: values) {
            byte[] code = coder.encode(v);
            int actual = coder.decode(code);
            System.out.println("expected: " + v + ", actual: " + actual + ", code: " + coder.toBinaryString(code));
            assert (coder.isValid(code));
            assert (v == actual);
        }

        for (int v: values) {
            String stringValue = String.valueOf(v);
            byte[] code = coder.fromDecimalString(stringValue);
            int actual = coder.decode(code);
            System.out.println("expected: " + v + ", actual: " + actual + ", code: " + coder.toBinaryString(code));
            assert (coder.isValid(code));
            assert (v == actual);
        }
    }

    private static void encodeDecodeTest(String[] values, IntegerCode coder) {
        for (String v: values) {
            byte[] code = coder.fromBinaryString(v);
            String actual = coder.toBinaryString(code);
            assert (actual.equals(v));
        }
    }

    private static void additionTest(int a, int b, IntegerCode coder) {
        int sum = a + b;
        assert (sum >= a);
        assert (sum >= b);

        byte[] aCode = coder.encode(a);
        byte[] bCode = coder.encode(b);
        byte[] sumCode = coder.add(aCode, bCode);
        int actualSum = coder.decode(sumCode);

        System.out.println("a: " + a + ", b: " + b + ", expected sum: " + sum + ", actual sum: " + actualSum +
                        ", code: " + coder.toBinaryString(sumCode));
        assert (coder.isValid(sumCode));
        assert (sum == actualSum);
    }

    private static void subtractionTest(int a, int b, IntegerCode coder) {
        int sub = a - b;
        byte[] aCode = coder.encode(a);
        byte[] bCode = coder.encode(b);
        byte[] subCode = coder.sub(aCode, bCode);
        int actualSub = coder.decode(subCode);

        System.out.println("a: " + a + ", b: " + b + ", expected sub: " + sub + ", actual sub: " + actualSub +
                ", code: " + coder.toBinaryString(subCode));
        assert (coder.isValid(subCode));
        assert (sub == actualSub);
    }

    private static void multiplicationTest(int a, int b, IntegerCode coder) {
        int expected = a*b;
        byte[] aBytes = coder.encode(a);
        byte[] bBytes = coder.encode(b);
        byte[] actualBytes = coder.mult(aBytes, bBytes);
        int actual = coder.decode(actualBytes);

        System.out.println("a: " + a + ", b: " + b + ", expected mult: " + expected + ", actual mult: " + actual +
                ", code: " + coder.toBinaryString(actualBytes));
        assert (coder.isValid(actualBytes));
        assert (expected == actual);
    }

    public static void entropyTest(Random.Distribution<Integer> distribution, int sampleSize, IntegerCode coder) {
        Random.DiscreteRandom<Integer> random = new Random.DiscreteRandom<>(distribution);
        int totalBytes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++) {
            int x = random.next();
            byte[] code = coder.encode(x);
            assert (coder.isValid(code));
            assert (x == coder.decode(code));
            totalBytes += code.length;
        }

        double averageBits = (double)totalBytes*8/(double)sampleSize;
        double entropy = Random.entropy(distribution);
        System.out.println("entropy: " + entropy + ", average bits per code: " + averageBits +
                ", sample size: " + sampleSize);
    }

    private static void largeIntegerTest(IntegerCode coder) {
        int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        byte[] aCode = coder.encode(a);
        byte[] aPlusOne = coder.add(aCode, coder.encode(2));
        byte[] aPlusOneMinusOne = coder.sub(aPlusOne, coder.encode(2));
        int backToA = coder.decode(aPlusOneMinusOne);
        assert (coder.isValid(aCode));
        assert (coder.isValid(aPlusOne));
        assert (coder.isValid(aPlusOneMinusOne));
        assert (a == backToA);

        int b = 5;
        byte[] bCode = coder.encode(b);
        byte[] largeProduct = coder.mult(aCode, bCode);
        byte[] remainder = largeProduct;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            remainder = coder.sub(remainder, aCode);
        }
        assert (coder.isValid(bCode));
        assert (coder.isValid(largeProduct));
        assert (coder.isValid(remainder));
        assert (coder.decode(remainder) == 0);

        //test largeProduct == (a-c)*b + c*b
        int c = 5000;
        byte[] cCode = coder.encode(c);
        byte[] aMinusC = coder.sub(aCode, cCode);
        byte[] aMinusCTimeB = coder.mult(aMinusC, bCode);
        byte[] cTimesB = coder.mult(bCode, cCode);
        byte[] backToLargeProduct = coder.add(aMinusCTimeB, cTimesB);
        assert (coder.isValid(cCode));
        assert (coder.isValid(aMinusC));
        assert (coder.isValid(aMinusCTimeB));
        assert (coder.isValid(cTimesB));
        assert (coder.isValid(backToLargeProduct));
        assert (coder.toBinaryString(largeProduct).equals(coder.toBinaryString(backToLargeProduct)));

        byte[] longMax = coder.fromDecimalString("9223372036854775807");
        byte[] twiceLongMax = coder.mult(longMax, coder.encode(2));
        byte[] backToLongMax = coder.sub(twiceLongMax, longMax);
        assert (coder.isValid(longMax));
        assert (coder.isValid(twiceLongMax));
        assert (coder.isValid(backToLongMax));
        assert (Arrays.equals(longMax, backToLongMax));

        byte[] veryLarge1 = coder.fromDecimalString("308956793729479789865799938561048");
        byte[] veryLarge2 = coder.fromDecimalString("19087456278490294783900464");
        byte[] expected = coder.fromDecimalString("308956812816936068356094722461512");
        byte[] actual = coder.add(veryLarge1, veryLarge2);
        assert (coder.isValid(veryLarge1));
        assert (coder.isValid(veryLarge2));
        assert (coder.isValid(expected));
        assert (coder.isValid(actual));
        assert (Arrays.equals(expected, actual));
        assert (Arrays.equals(veryLarge2, coder.sub(actual, veryLarge1)));

        actual = coder.mult(coder.encode(5), veryLarge1);
        expected = coder.fromDecimalString("1544783968647398949328999692805240");
        assert (coder.isValid(actual));
        assert (coder.isValid(expected));
        assert (Arrays.equals(actual, expected));

        System.out.println("all large integer tests pass");
    }

    private static void test1(IntegerCode coder) {
        //encode and int, then decode
        int[] values = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 8, 127, 128, 137, 146, 160, 288, 306, 56, 250,
                                    16383, 16385, 2097152, 6789989, 80000000};
        System.out.println("encode decode test (integers)");
        System.out.println("================================");
        encodeDecodeTest(values, coder);

        //add two integers
        System.out.println("addition test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        additionTest(0, 0, coder);
        additionTest(0, 1, coder);
        additionTest(1, 0, coder);
        additionTest(1, 1, coder);
        additionTest(4, 3, coder);
        additionTest(6, 9, coder);
        additionTest(12, 56, coder);
        additionTest(120, 10, coder);
        additionTest(10, 120, coder);
        additionTest(120, 0, coder);
        additionTest(120, 130, coder);
        additionTest(127, 1, coder);

        //subtract two integers
        System.out.println("subtraction test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        subtractionTest(0, 0, coder);
        subtractionTest(1, 0, coder);
        subtractionTest(1, 1, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 0, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 1, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 12, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 8, coder);
        subtractionTest(2097152, 0, coder);
        subtractionTest(2097152, 1, coder);
        subtractionTest(2097152, 2097152, coder);
        subtractionTest(2097152, 2097102, coder);
        subtractionTest(306, 160, coder);
        subtractionTest(306, 288, coder);
        subtractionTest(306, 56, coder);

        //multiply two integers
        System.out.println("multiplication test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        multiplicationTest(1, 1, coder);
        multiplicationTest(1, 0, coder);
        multiplicationTest(0, 1, coder);
        multiplicationTest(0, 0, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 0, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 1, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 2, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 3, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 5, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 127, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 128, coder);
        multiplicationTest(136, 3, coder);
        multiplicationTest(136, 129, coder);

        //average bits per code
        System.out.println("entropy test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        Integer[] data = new Integer[100000];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = i;
        }
        int[] counts = new int[data.length];
        //uniform distribution
        System.out.println("uniform probability distribution");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        Arrays.fill(counts, 5);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 500, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 1000, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 2000, coder);
        //monotonic increasing: linear
        System.out.println("monotonic increasing probability (linear)");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            counts[i] = i+1;
        }
        //the following tests are throwing crazy numbers: entropy==95.77, average bits per code==22.5.
        // the reason this is happening is because, the cumulative frequency of the distribution is adding up to
        // 1 at about 37000. so, a sum of 37000 very small (between 10^(-8) and 10^(-3)), mutually exclusive,
        // non-exhaustive probabilities represented as Java double type, is > 1. this is probably due to
        // approximations in floating point arithmetic. as a result of this problem, the DiscreteRandom generator
        // used to generate the sample from the distribution only generates numbers <= 37000. thus, the average
        // bits per code calculated from the sample is much smaller than the entropy of the distribution.
        // possible solution is to use BigDecimal to represent the probabilities. or, use a hierarchy of DiscreteRandom
        // generators, one to select a range, next one to select a subrange and so on, till we have a generator that
        // can handle the range of doubles without encountering the arithmetic approximation problem.
        // references:
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217636/java-sum-of-all-double-does-not-return-expected-result
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625556/java-adding-and-subtracting-doubles-are-giving-strange-results (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15625600)
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java (http://stackoverflow.com/a/322875)
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 500, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 1000, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 2000, coder);
        //monotonic increasing: quadratic
        System.out.println("monotonic increasing probability (quadratic)");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            counts[i] = (i+1)*(i+1);
        }
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 500, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 1000, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 2000, coder);
        //monotonic decreasing: linear
        System.out.println("monotonic decreasing probability (linear)");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            counts[i] = counts.length - i;
        }
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 500, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 1000, coder);
        entropyTest(Random.buildDistribution(data, counts), 2000, coder);

        //test integers > Integer.MAX_VALUE
        System.out.println("large integer test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        largeIntegerTest(coder);
    }

    private static void test2(IntegerCode coder) {
        //encode and int, then decode
        int[] values = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 8, 127, 128, 137};
        System.out.println("encode decode test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        encodeDecodeTest(values, coder);

        //add two integers
        System.out.println("addition test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        additionTest(0, 0, coder);
        additionTest(0, 1, coder);
        additionTest(1, 0, coder);
        additionTest(1, 1, coder);
        additionTest(4, 3, coder);
        additionTest(6, 9, coder);
        additionTest(12, 56, coder);
        additionTest(120, 10, coder);
        additionTest(10, 120, coder);
        additionTest(120, 0, coder);
        additionTest(120, 130, coder);
        additionTest(127, 1, coder);

        //subtract two integers
        System.out.println("subtraction test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        subtractionTest(0, 0, coder);
        subtractionTest(1, 0, coder);
        subtractionTest(1, 1, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 0, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 1, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 12, coder);
        subtractionTest(12, 8, coder);
        subtractionTest(2097152, 2097152, coder);
        subtractionTest(2097152, 2097102, coder);
        subtractionTest(306, 160, coder);
        subtractionTest(306, 288, coder);
        subtractionTest(306, 56, coder);

        //multiply two integers
        System.out.println("multiplication test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        multiplicationTest(1, 1, coder);
        multiplicationTest(1, 0, coder);
        multiplicationTest(0, 1, coder);
        multiplicationTest(0, 0, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 0, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 1, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 2, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 3, coder);
        multiplicationTest(27, 5, coder);

        //test integers > Integer.MAX_VALUE
        System.out.println("large integer test");
        System.out.println("================================");
        largeIntegerTest(coder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerCode vlqCoder = new VLQ();
        System.out.println("Testing VLQ base 128 (default base)");
        System.out.println("================================================");
        test1(vlqCoder);
        String[] stringValues = new String[] {
                "00000000",
                "00001010",
                "10001010 00110010",
                "10001010 11110111 00110010",
                "10011010 11111111 10110011 10101100 10110011 11111111 10101011 01000000",
                "10011010 11111111 10110011 10101100 10110011 11111111 11101000 10101011 01000000",
                "10011010 10000111 11111111 10110011 10101100 10110011 11111111 11101000 10101011 01000000",
        };
        System.out.println("encode decode test (strings)");
        System.out.println("================================");
        encodeDecodeTest(stringValues, vlqCoder);


        System.out.println("Testing VLQ base 10");
        System.out.println("================================================");
        IntegerCode vlqCoderBase10 = new VLQ(10);
        test1(vlqCoderBase10);

        System.out.println("Testing VLQ base 2");
        System.out.println("================================================");
        IntegerCode vlqCoderBase2 = new VLQ(2);
        test2(vlqCoderBase2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough you assert that `a` and `b` in the tests are positive, but you never do such a thing in `encode(..)`. From what I understand, passing a negative number to `encode(..)` will result in nonsense.

Comment: @Sumurai8 thanks! what you say makes sense. I'll add input validation in `encode()` rather than in tests.

Answer (score 4):

Let me get two things out of the way: I won't even bother to comment on your naming, let alone comment on the fact that you're abusing `IntegerEncoding` as a namespace.

#### Assert is not argument validation

Using assert to validate arguments is bad practice. Instead of having an `AssertionError` (which is dangerous) you should throw one of `IllegalArgumentException`, `NullPointerException` or in rare cases `IllegalStateException`.

Quoting the [JLS on `assert` (§14.10)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10):

> In light of this, assertions should not be used for argument checking in public methods. Argument checking is typically part of the contract of a method, and this contract must be upheld whether assertions are enabled or disabled.

#### Minor and Major nitpicks

- `ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();` should instead be declared as `List<Byte>`. Favor interfaces over implementations
- `StringUtils#isNotBlank` introduces a huge dependency. If your code only uses that it's significantly more effective to just rely on `Objects#requireNonNull` and `String#trim().length()` to check the same thing (in even better granularity).
- Binary operators should always have a space on either side. I see one violation in #decode (`result += b*multiplier`). **Use your IDE's linting tools!**
- Your methods are incredibly long. Additionally a significant number of variables is declared in them. Most of them could be smaller in scope if done correctly, in other places you should extract smaller methods to do less abstract work for you.

#### Testing

Your testing code is *one huge nightmare*.

- You're not automating anything
- You're not using a Test-Framework to handle basic setup and teardown for you
- You have tests with over 50 LoC for a single functionality
- You have magic strings and magic numbers all over the place
- You have a 15 line comment in a test...
- And you're verifying significant portions of output by manually checking sysouts ...

All of this means that your test-suite is unusable. Utterly unusable for basically anything that's professional software development.

To fix this I strongly suggest you look into unit-testing frameworks like JUnit and TestNG

Comment: thanks for the comments. any thoughts on how do I avoid magic strings and numbers in test code?

Comment: the tests rely on asserts and are fully automated. the println()s exist as they helped at some point in the past. outputs don't need manual inspection anymore. 

I'm familiar with the unit test frameworks you mentioned. however, for a simple scenario such as this project (no setup/tear down requirements, no organizational reporting), I feel either of them is undue complication. these simple assert based tests take care of my most important requirement that incremental changes don't break the functionality.